# regular expressions on sql file

Tags: regex, notepad++, sql-scripts

I need to perform a search and replace operation on hundreds of SQL script files. The idea is to transform this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_whatever]
    (
      @id INT,
      @parameter VARCHAR(1)
    )
AS 
    BEGIN
        ...
    END
```

Into this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[proc_whatever]') IS NULL
      EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_whatever] AS SET NOCOUNT ON;')
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_whatever]
    (
      @id INT,
      @parameter VARCHAR(1)
    )
AS 
    BEGIN
        ...
    END
```

To do this I would use *Notepad++*.

Any tip or ideas?

Comment: thanks to all those who answered. i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex replacement:

```
Find What:     CREATE\s+PROCEDURE\s+(\[.*?\]\.\[.*?\])\s+\(\s+(@id INT,\s+@parameter VARCHAR\(\d+\)\s+)\s+\)
Replace With:  IF OBJECT_ID\('$1'\) IS NULL\r\n    EXEC\('CREATE PROCEDURE $1 AS SET NOCOUNT ON;'\)\r\nGO\r\n\r\nALTER PROCEDURE $1\r\n    \(\r\n      $2\)
```

Tested:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

search:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ([\[\]a-zA-Z_.]+)\s*\(
```

replace in:

```
IF OBJECT_ID \('$1'\) IS NULL \n EXEC \('CREATE PROCEDURE $1  AS SET NOCOUNT ON;'\) \n GO \n ALTER PROCEDURE $1 \(
```